# Appium automation in android getting below issue while ruining test case

Tags: android, appium

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\DIVAYA~1.P\AppData\Local\Temp\20231128-12820-1wmez4c.zk1j\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'. Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1' must exist)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you check that the JAVA_HOME path points to the correct directory?

Comment: yes pointed to jdk 11 i m using windows

Comment: how to set two different java_home version one for appium & one for android studio?